# How do i create account remotely?

Tags: wallets, accounts, rpc

I have two servers, one for eth-node, one for web api and user db.

I want to send request to create account from web server to eth server, but i see it can be created by running command like `geth account new` localy.
https://medium.com/@tzhenghao/getting-started-with-geth-c1a30b8d6458

The purpose of this account is to receive and spend eth, which will be mapped with user-account on user-db server.

Anyway to remotely create account from the eth server then get returned address then store it to the user-web server?

I've read the `ethclient`, but it shows the way to create wallet only, not account
https://goethereumbook.org/accounts/

Or i have to write a service on eth server to exec command `geth account new` to get result and return it to the user-web server?

Comment: you need to use web3js to create accounts

Comment: @wandos i've searched for web3 go client , but there is no reliable library, only python, js, since go-eth was written in Go, but there's no official go-client to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web3Js to do so. Based on Web3Js documentation you can use the code below to create an account using a web3js call. Make sure you use the right version web3js the code below is for v1.0+ beta.

Link to documentation:

[Documentation link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html)

Sample Code:

```
 web3.eth.accounts.create();
> {
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}

web3.eth.accounts.create('2435@#@#@±±±±!!!!678543213456764321§34567543213456785432134567');
> {
    address: "0xF2CD2AA0c7926743B1D4310b2BC984a0a453c3d4",
    privateKey: "0xd7325de5c2c1cf0009fac77d3d04a9c004b038883446b065871bc3e831dcd098",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}

web3.eth.accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32));
> {
    address: "0xe78150FaCD36E8EB00291e251424a0515AA1FF05",
    privateKey: "0xcc505ee6067fba3f6fc2050643379e190e087aeffe5d958ab9f2f3ed3800fa4e",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

Comment: i though `web3.eth.accounts.create` can be used for local node only? for remote node we have to use `web3.personal.newAccount` , i got error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'create'` if i use `web3.eth.accounts.create` on web3py